# Extract all numbers from list of lists

Tags: python

Is there a simple function that can extract all numbers from a list of lists. For example:

```
l = [ [1,2], [1, 5], [2] ] -> [1,2,1,5,2]
```

i would like to avoid using loops or list comprehensions.

Comment: this operation is called _list flattening_. Google it.

Comment: Do all of the inner lists contain just numbers? If so, this is a definite duplicate. If not, a layer of filtering needs to be added. Also, why would you want to avoid a list comprehension when constructing a list? It is the most pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.chain`

**Demo:**

```
import itertools
l = [ [1,2], [1, 5], [2] ] 
print(list(itertools.chain(*l))) #or print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 1, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to avoid using loops or list comprehensions.

You can use `itertools.chain` method in combination with `Extended iterable unpacking` operator.

`chain` method makes an *iterator* that *returns* elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

```
import itertools
merged = list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

Output

```
[1,2,1,5,2]
```

Another approach is to use `reduce` function.

```
l = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: @Biskit1943 OP said so

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> x = [j for i in l for j in i]
[1, 2, 1, 5, 2]
```